# Python not read file

Tags: python, file

```
tempfile = "temp.txt"   
runc = get_config_ssh(ipSw,cisco_user,cisco_pass,"show switch")
outfile = open(tempfile, "w")
outfile.write(runc)   
outfile.close
nstack = 0

with open(tempfile) as infp:
    data = infp.read()
print data
```

Tshoot:
1- temp.txt file after execution contains the data but if I try to read with python don't show any result.

2 - If I change the command, for example "show int status" that I issue to the switch, it works, it print the data readed by python scrypt

3 - show switch and show int status both command outputs are in clear text and both are present in the temp.txt file after execution.

There is a problem with write method?

SSH Connection write data int temp.txt file but when I read it later (witch open....) print data not show any result.

Anyone can help me with this issue?
Thanks

Comment: If you open the file outside of python, does it contain data?

Comment: maybe do a `print(runc)` and see if it has something or not. Maybe you are writing empty strings to file

Comment: Yes, the file cotain data and print(runc) works. Strange hear is that if I change the command that I send to switch, for example "show int status" it works. There Is another method to write text in python?

Comment: You need to call `outfile.close()`, otherwise data may only be flushed after exiting the programm, so you are missing the `()`. Why do you use a context manager only for reading the file?

Comment: Thanks @strippenzieher this is the issue.

Comment: You would have been better off using a `with` block for writing, like you do for reading.

Answer (score 0):

Need to call `outfile.close()`, otherwise data may only be flushed after exiting the programm, so you are missing the `()`

Answer (score -1):

Try adding the reading mode

```
with open(tempfile, "r") as infp:
    data = infp.read()
print data
```